# How can carrier limit hot spot connections

Tags: iphone, ios, tethering, cellular-carriers

I have encountered this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82276/does-ios-7-cellular-tethering-limit-the-number-of-wifi-clients) and in accepted answer there is information that doesn't click

> For instance, the iPhone 5 should theoretically be able to handle up to 14 connections, but both AT&T and Verizon limits it to 5.

How can carrier limit hot spot connections?

To clarify I own iPhone that uses sim card, and live in Europe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between *theoretical* and *actual* performance.

*Theoretically*, the wireless hardware inside the iPhone may be able to do more than 5 connections at once, but Apple and the carriers have limited it to 5 for power and data usage reasons.  It's highly likely that having more than 5 connected devices would overwhelm your phone's battery, Wi-Fi radio, and cellular radio.

Think about something like the CPU inside your phone: it can technically run at 1GHz or higher, but if iOS ran the CPU at full tilt all the time, your phone would get really hot and the battery would die really quickly.  Instead, iOS makes sure to only run the CPU at full tilt when you're doing something intensive (like photo editing or playing a game), and brings it back to low speed when you stop running the game (or the phone gets too hot).

As for carrier control, the iPhone (and cellular iPad) can download **carrier profiles** over-the-air and tell your phone how to connect to the cellular network and what restrictions exist (such as whether tethering is allowed or not).

Comment: Yes I am sorry I didn't add much details in question. I know about the hardware limits my iPhone 5 while charging and on 4g network (and hot spoting) is really warm, I also know about the profiles (carrier firmware) but that can be removed if I am not mistaken, I was wondering if carrier "tracks" and somehow knows that I am sending requests from x different devices on BTS layer.

Comment: Your phone can report that information back to the carrier network.  From a network perspective, no, I don't think they can identify it.  However, remember that tethering talks to a different APN, so your carrier will know that you're using the tethering feature.

Answer (score 2):

It's baked into the iOS as a configurable number and the carriers submit carrier profiles that contain their preferred limits.

When the first iPhone came out there were legitimate concerns it would crash the carrier since they didn’t have controls to manage usage. This close alignment between the carriers and Apple exists to this day granting them control over many aspects of the radio configuration.

Comment: Haha, easy! This is what I was essentially looking for. Its baked in iOS.